# How to wait till a task is fully completed?

Tags: c#, .net, image, task

I have a image processing application in which I have 2 modes. Manual inspection and Automatic inspection using a PLC command.
Manual inspection works fine, the user clicks a button to grab an image, and then clicks another button to process the image and send results to the PLC.
But in automatic inspection mode, im getting incorrect inspection result(same product/image  inspection in manual mode gets correct result). I suspect that after grabbing image the system is not getting enough time to read the full image before the inspection starts, so I added a thread.sleep(500), But that didnt make any difference. So I tried the async await.task.delay(500) method, same result.

Is there any other way to fix it?

Code:

```
 private async void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btncheckm1_Click(null, null);
        var newSignal = textBox8.Text.Contains("+1");
        var isRisingEdge = newSignal && (_oldSignal == false);
        _oldSignal = newSignal;


        if (isRisingEdge)
        {

            lblmessages.Text = "";

            totalsheetcount++;

            btngrabimage_Click(null, null);

           // Thread.Sleep(300);
            await Task.Delay(1000);

           processimage();

        }


    }
```

btngrabimage() has the following code:

```
      try
        {
        camimage = null;
        cam1.BeginAcquisition();
        // Retrieve an image 
        IManagedImage rawImage = cam1.GetNextImage();

        IManagedImage convertedImage = rawImage.Convert(PixelFormatEnums.Mono8);


        imagetoinspect = convertedImage.bitmap;          
        rawImage.Release();
        cam1.EndAcquisition();
        //cam1.DeInit();
        distort();
        }

        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
```

Comment: I would expect some kind of awaiting here `btngrabimage_Click`. Can we see the code?

Comment: HI, Have added the code to the question.

Comment: Is it async? You missed the signature

Comment: btngrabimage_Click is not async

Comment: @SirRufo hi, can you please share how do i add a task?

Comment: Ok, please guide me how to fix my problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I also would say that wrapping the grabbing of an image inside a task and awaiting that result is the way to go. The image class represents your return type as the image. Dont mind the function names though. Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew are essentially the same thing, just wanted to show you have different options for creating your task

```
    public class ImageRetriever
    { 
        public void ProcessImage()
        {
            //if you would like to get rid of the async
            //reminder that calling .Result is blocking for the current thread.
            //this means the thread will stop working untill the result is returned
            //could be an issue if this is called on UI thead
            var imageTask = GetImage();
            Image image = imageTask.Result;
        }

        public async Task ProcessImageAsync()
        {
            //if you want to keep the async-nonblocking
            Image image = await GetImage();
        } 
        private Task<Image> GetImage()
        {
            //this is how your create your task
            Task<Image> imageTask;
            imageTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return new Image();
            });
            // or
            imageTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return new Image();
            });
            return imageTask;
        }
    }

    public class Image
    {

    }
```